# Concatenating two strings iteratively in C++

Tags: c++, string-concatenation

I know a string concatenation question has been asked to death in SE. But to the best of my knowledge,I've gone through all the questions that could help me, in vain.

This is what I am hoping to accomplish with this program:

Initially I have a=0 and b=1, for n=0 and n=1 respectively.

For the next input  i.e from n=3 onwards, my result should be concatenation of the previous two strings. (Like a Fibonacci sequence; only the addition is replaced by concatenation)

So,for example:
For n=3, my output should be "10".
For n=4, my output should be "101"
For n=5, my output should be "10110"

There is no logical problem with the code I've written,but I'm getting a SIGSEGV error and I don't see why.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<new>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long int n,i;
    char *a="0";
    char *b="1";
    char *c=new char[100000];

cout<<"Enter  a number n:";
cin>>n;

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{

    strcat(b,a);
    strcpy(a,b);

}
cout<<"\nRequired string="<<b;
```

}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you forgot to use c :)

Comment: I did intend to use 'c',but I found that it was an unnecessary variable to work with :) Just forgot that I'd declared it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`strcat(b,a);` invokes undefined behaviour because `b` points to a string literal.

```
char * strcat ( char * destination, const char * source );
```

> Concatenate strings
>   Appends a copy of the `source` string to the `destination` string.

Since this is C++, I suggest you use `std::string` and the `+` operator. Or a `std::stringstream`.

Comment: Yes, I understand now :) And mission accomplished :D Thank you.

Comment: +1 for suggesting `std::string`/`std::stringstream`, you can never say it enough times.

Answer (score 3):

The problem that you are observing has to do with undefined behavior: you are writing to the memory that has been allocated to a string literal.

To avoid the issue, you should switch to using C++ `std::string`: it makes your code a lot simpler by taking memory management out of the picture.

```
string a("0");
string b("1");
int n = 10;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
    string tmp(a);
    a = b;
    b = tmp + b;
}
cout<<"Required string="<<b;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char *a="0";
char *b="1";
```

"0" and "1" are `string-literals` (a has address of "0" and b has address of "1"), change of its contains is `undefined behaviour`.

```
strcat(b,a);
strcpy(a,b);
```

UB.

Since you use C++ better use `std::string` or `std::stringstream`.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `a` and `b` as

```
char *a="0"; 
char *b="1";
```

These are pointers to constant strings. This means that the memory allocated to these pointers is fixed. When you write past this block of memory, Bad Things(TM) will happen.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `strcat` but your destination string is a string literal. `strcat` is then attempting to write past that strings terminating null character and that is where the seg fault comes in. Just don't try to modify string literals at all. Since you have the luxury of using C++ unless this is a learning exercise you would be much better off using std::string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code instead, I am showing to you that you need to think of the inital values of n = 1, 2
also you should handle wrong inputs with n < 0
and avoid dynamic allocation as you seems to use new for no obvious reason and you forgot to free the memory with delete at the end.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<new>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long int n,i;
    char a[10];
    char b[10];
    char c[10];
    //char *c=new char[100000];
    cout<<"Enter  a number n:";
    cin>>n;

    strcpy(a, "0");
    strcpy(b, "1");

    if (n == 1)
        strcpy(b, a);
    else if (n > 2)
    {
        for(i=2;i<n;i++)
        {
            strcpy(c, a);
            strcat(c, b);
            strcpy(a, b);
            strcpy(b,c);
        }
    }
    else if (n != 2)
        cout<<"\nInvalid input!";

    cout<<"\nRequired string="<<b;
```

}

Comment: I tried this approach initially and although it's simple, it will not do for larger strings as the value of n increases